# About React Native, Redux , ListView and Navigator

Tags: listview, reactjs, react-native, redux, navigator

I find it impossible to show all the code because is too much, but my question is on `React Native`, `Redux`, `ListView` and `Navigator`.

My Redux state store a items Array, beautifully presented in a `ListView` , the `onPress` on an item, push the `Navigator` to another scene where the item details are presented. When I fired a redux action (from a props) ie: `Click` (which updates a value in the Redux Store ), the actions is fired, and appears on debug console, but the element on the screen is not updated, If I return back to ListView it appears updated.

I tried all kinds of imaginative code as `navigator.replace` to the same route after dispatching the redux action but does not work.

I've forgotten to do anything?

---

I write a small code to show an explain better what i do not understand about refresh the screen.

The code is in this question
[Need help on some concepts about ReactNative and Redux and Navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535456/need-help-on-some-concepts-about-reactnative-and-redux-and-navigator)

I really need help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since your question lacks code, its hard to guess what you are actually doing. However I would go ahead and take a guess - `redux` is modifying `props` and you do not have any state set which is getting updated.

If you read the [official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#how-state-works):

> A common way to inform React of a data change is by calling
>   setState(data, callback). This method merges data into this.state and
>   re-renders the component. When the component finishes re-rendering,
>   the optional callback is called. Most of the time you'll never need to
>   provide a callback since React will take care of keeping your UI
>   up-to-date for you.

Following this, I would suggest whichever attribute of props is changing, you can set it as a state. You can then write conditions based on `state` in your `render` method.

Something like:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { someprop: this.props.someprop };
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps : function(nextProps) {
    this.setState({someprop: nextProps.someprop});
  },
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          { this.state.someprop == "something" ? <ChildComp1 /> : <ChildComp2 />
        </div>
      );
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you well understand my question , and you answered with an approach that had not tried .

I'm trying to make an app AllInOne showing the problem.

In your answer, you have guided me to the function `shouldComponentUpdate ( nextProps , nextstate )`, but do not get anything other than my original props , although the state has been updated redux .

I keep trying , but it seems strange that no more information about this issue around.