# Need help on some concepts about ReactNative and Redux and Navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, navigator, react-redux

After several tests in this scenario, I have some questions that I can not answer my self, so I ask for help to clarify my concepts.

1. **Provider vs props in Navigator**

What is the difference and what is the best approach to setup the Navigator and pass store to different Scenes of a React Native app

```jsx
export default class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>                        //<-- here
        <Navigator style={{flex: 1}}
        initialRoute={{ component: MainContainer }} //<-- here 

          renderScene={ (route, navigator) => {
            const Component = route.component;
            return (
              <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop:40}}>
                <Component navigator={navigator} route={route} {...route.passProps} />
              </View>
  ...
```

`MainContainer` is connected with `Component` within react-redux `connect` function to pass Props and Actions to `props`.

Is it better access to context or to props?

vs

```jsx
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer, initialState); //<-- here
export default class App extends Component {
render () {
  return (
    <Navigator style={{flex: 1}}
      initialRoute={{ component: MainComponent }}

      renderScene={ (route, navigator) => {
      const Component = route.component;
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop:40}}>
          <Component 
             navigator={navigator} 
             route={route} 
             {...route.passProps} 
             store={store}                      //<-- here
               />
       </View>
    ...
```

2. In a component Scene, (not wrapping as a smart container) how to setup a **listener** about changes in **redux state** or have i to bind **component state** to redux state.

Passing `state` (of Redux store) and `actions` as `passProps` when pushing `newScene` in `Navigator`, and in then `newScene` dispatch actions and executed correctly, the state is update, but... does not re-render the scene.

Do I have to bind state component to Redux state to see the changes reflected on screen?

Is there any sample about best practices in this scenario?

3. **`props`** vs **`connect`** in the same `Scene`

In the **same `Scene`**, **from Top to Down components**, which is the best approach to pass `redux state` (not talking about `component state`) as wrapping a component in a `'smart' container` with '`connect`' from `react-redux`, or passing the hole scenario as `props`.

Comment: It would be cool if you could split your questions to several posts for the next time, you will get most likely faster responses for the individually ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. The first solution should be used, as the provider should be the outermost component (so that everything underneath may connect properly).
2. You could either run a callback on `componentDidReceiveProps` or (what I would prefer) simply connect the component, which needs access to a store. This is exactly what redux is for. The only reason not to do this is if you would like to reuse a component with another stores content (truly representational component)
3. This strongly depends on the application and the depth of the components but in general, this is completely okay. You may also pass the information as props, but as your application grows bigger you may have to pass a lot of props, which may obfuscate the real intend of you components